# Python-numpy: Specifying item size of a compound data type doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dt = np.dtype({"names": ["First"], 
                   "formats": [np.uint32], 
                   "offsets": [3], 
                   "itemsize": 8})
>>> dt.itemsize
7
```

Comment: Can you point to the documentation for "itemsize" in numpy?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.itemsize.html#numpy.dtype.itemsize

From the documentation of the initializer I'm using:

The itemsize key allows the total size of the dtype to be set, and must be an integer large enough so all the fields are within the dtype. If the dtype being constructed is aligned, the itemsize must also be divisible by the struct alignment.

Comment: I just checked it. True, it looks like a bug.

Comment: I manipulated formats and offsets a bit, and it looks like itemsize being returned is the itemsize for formats + number of offsets.  So, if format is np.int64 and offset is 2, then itemsize returned is 10.  Why?  I have no idea..!

Comment: Yes, that's where the 7 comes from: an offset of 3 and an item size of 4. But it's still not what I specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me. But if you just need n bytes of padding at the end a composite type may help:

```
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype({"names": ["First", "_"], 
               "formats": [np.uint32, (np.void,1)], 
               "offsets": [3,7],
})
arr = np.empty( (5,), dtype=dt )
```

Comment: Actually, this is kind of nice as it will save a bit of memory, so I just adjust the size of the buffers I use to populate the ensuing array according to the item size. It's a decent workaround.